# React useState - FaStar icons - Click To Change and Change Back

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am learning React JS and spending some time with useState.

I have the following code (also available on sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/starswithclicks-dlhjh

```
import React from "react";
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useState } from "react";

const Star = ({ selected = false, StarClicked = (f) => f }) => (
  <FaStar color={selected ? "red" : "grey"} onClick={StarClicked} />
);

function StarRating() {
  const [firstStar, setfirstStar] = useState(false);
  const [secondStar, setSecondStar] = useState(false);
  const [thirdStar, setThirdStar] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Stars will come here</p>
      <Star
        selected={true}
        StarClicked={() => {
          setfirstStar(true);
          setSecondStar(true);
          setThirdStar(true);
        }}
      />
      <Star
        selected={firstStar}
        StarClicked={() => {
          setfirstStar(true);
          setSecondStar(false);
          setThirdStar(false);
        }}
      />
      <Star
        selected={secondStar}
        StarClicked={() => {
          setfirstStar(false);
          setSecondStar(true);
          setThirdStar(false);
        }}
      />
      <Star
        selected={thirdStar}
        StarClicked={() => {
          setfirstStar(false);
          setSecondStar(false);
          setThirdStar(true);
        }}
      />
      <Star
        selected={false}
        StarClicked={() => {
          setfirstStar(false);
          setSecondStar(false);
          setThirdStar(false);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default StarRating;
```

Right now, I have managed to get the following working with the above code, a simple exercise I gave myself.

- first star, on click, turns on all three middle stars
- last star, on click, turns off all three middle star
- any of the middle star, on click, turns on, and turns off the other two.

Now, I want to show a simple message on the screen, if a star (of the middle three) is already on. For example.

1. In the beginning, all three middle stars are grey.
2. I click the middle one, and it turns red.
3. I click on the middle one again, a simple message appears below, saying that it is already on.

Essentially, I want to check if a given star's selected property is true or false, and accordingly, show a simple message at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a call to a parent method (using props) to show an error on the click event, if the state already set.

see example with start index in error at the parent: https://codesandbox.io/s/starswithclicks-forked-4m3j5?file=/src/StarRating.js

Parent:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [haseError, setShowError] = useState(false);
  const showError = () => {
    setShowError(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Basic State Practice</h1>
      <StarRating showError={showError} />
      {haseError ? <div> star already clicked</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And a star example

```js
 <Star
        selected={secondStar}
        StarClicked={() => {
          if (secondStar) props.showError();
          setfirstStar(false);
          setSecondStar(true);
          setThirdStar(false);
        }}
      />
```

### EDIT

You could do the same in StarRating component: https://codesandbox.io/s/starswithclicks-forked-kfnho?file=/src/StarRating.js

```js
function StarRating(props) {
  const [firstStar, setfirstStar] = useState(false);
  const [secondStar, setSecondStar] = useState(false);
  const [thirdStar, setThirdStar] = useState(false);
  const [clickedStar, setShowError] = useState(-1);
  const showError = (index) => {
    setShowError(index);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Stars will come here</p>
      <Star
        selected={true}
        StarClicked={() => {
          setfirstStar(true);
          setSecondStar(true);
          setThirdStar(true);
        }}
      />
      <Star
        selected={firstStar}
        StarClicked={() => {
          if (firstStar) showError(2);
          setfirstStar(true);
          setSecondStar(false);
          setThirdStar(false);
        }}
      />
      <Star
        selected={secondStar}
        StarClicked={() => {
          if (secondStar) showError(3);
          setfirstStar(false);
          setSecondStar(true);
          setThirdStar(false);
        }}
      />
      <Star
        selected={thirdStar}
        StarClicked={() => {
          if (thirdStar) showError(4);
          setfirstStar(false);
          setSecondStar(false);
          setThirdStar(true);
        }}
      />
      <Star
        selected={false}
        StarClicked={() => {
          setfirstStar(false);
          setSecondStar(false);
          setThirdStar(false);
        }}
      />
      {clickedStar >= 0 ? <div> star {clickedStar} already clicked</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ah! right, I was hoping to have a div in star rating itself. instead of thinking of it as a error, I want to look at as a visual sentence confirmation. so, as we click around, it will say, something like 'first star is clicked", "all of them are on".."this star is ALREADY clicked". but, your solution has given me a idea. I will check and update back. I would like to avoid sending anything up to App.js ideally.

Comment: you could do the same in the star component!

Comment: Added example to answer

Comment: perfect. this is what I was looking for

Comment: btw just added hiding the error on other start click to the latter code sandbox link